# Non-linear system of 3 equations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a system of 3 equations with the unknown $(x,y,z)$ to solve in the space $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}_+^{*}$ : 
$$m=x-y \\ v=x^2(z-1) \\\gamma=x^3(z^3+3z-2)$$

with $m \in \mathbb{R}$, $v>0$ , $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z>1$

Numerically, I easily find the solution with a solver, but I cannot figure out whether a closed-form formula of the solution exists.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you can treat the two equations in $x,z$ as a separate pair and solve those, then finish by solving the first.  Have you attempted to factor $z^3+3z-2$?

Comment: Actually, $z>1$, I tried but I end up solving $$\gamma=(z^3+3z-2)*(\frac{v}{z-1})^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

A standard way to solve the last two equations, would be to square the last and cube the other to solve for $z$ (expect when $x=0$, but in this case $y=-m$ and $z$ can be anything):
$$
v³(z³+3z-2)²-\gamma^2(z-1)³ = 0
$$
This gives a sixth order polynomial that you still have to check for extraneous solutions (as we have squared and lost the sign of $\gamma$ and $x$). But than, using the second, we get:
$$
x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{v}{z-1}}
$$
Which also requires $z>1$ for a solution, and finally using the first one:
$$
y = x - m
$$

Comment: Yes, exactly, but how do I solve the first equation ? I feel anyhow I need to you use a numerical solver .

Comment: It is not possible if you cannot reduce the degree of the polynomial with some cleaver trick, which does not seems to be possible as your coefficients depends on the parameters.